# Using Webview within Class Method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa

Basically I have a class method which I am calling to call a web-service call as in dispatch mechanism, and when I get the response, I send the response in NSDictionary in sync mode.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    NSDictionary *_pD= [HttpRequest Details:@"Type" :@"guest" :[Description valueForKey:@"number"]];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        DLog(@"%@",[_D description]);
        [self mapObjects:_D];

    });
});
```

However, in this call I need to also invoke WebView, and wait for a javascript to get invoked from webview, hence I am just curious if that is possible to do also in Class method? Since in class method, anytime I assigned a delegate, it generates an error that I cant assign it to self.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a static instance of your class being the delegate, and handle the entire thing from there.
Also remember to set the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol in your .h

```
+ (YourClass *)getInstance {
    static YourClass *instance = nil;
    if (!instance) {
        instance = [YourClass new];
    }
    return instance;
}

- (void)callWebService {
    ... do your thing
}
```

and call like this:

```
[[YourClass getInstance] callWebService];
```

If you want to get picky on the getInstance method, the proper way to do it is this (I didn't want to confuse you with weird code):

```
+ (YourClass *)getInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static YourClass *instance = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        instance = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    });

    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Ismael, isn't this the same as Singleton? Thanks. Btw, that's a good approach. I am just curious, if I can create instance as "webview" there in dispatch_async and load webview, and once loaded I can return the view.

Answer (score 0):

> Since in class method, anytime I assigned a delegate, it generates an
>   error that I cant assign it to self.

Just a quick thought. Why don't you write a new class and assign its object as the delegate instead of self?

Comment: I am curious how that can be done? Any examples to co-relate to that thought?